# Save the File in a single text file and also in the path i specified

Tags: c#, string

Hi all i have done a code to save my file as follows

```
       if (m_strStandardEntryClassCode == "PPD")
        {
            m_strPath += "/PPD_BatchHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
        }
        else
        {
            m_strPath += "/CCD_BatchHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
        }
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(m_strPath))
        {
            tw.Write(m_strRecordTypeCode.PadLeft(1, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strServiceClassCode.PadLeft(3, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyName.PadRight(16, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyDiscretionaryData.PadRight(20, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyIdentification.PadRight(10, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strStandardEntryClassCode.PadRight(3, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyEntryDescription.PadRight(10, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyDescriptiveDate.PadLeft(6, '0'));
            string m_strEffDate = m_strEffectiveEntryDate.Replace("/", "");
            tw.Write(m_strEffDate.PadLeft(6, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strOriginatorStatusCode.PadRight(1, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strOriginationDFIIdentification.PadLeft(8, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strBatchNumber.PadLeft(7, '0'));
            tw.Flush();
            tw.Close();
        }
```

Now i would like to save those two files in to single file and also as a multiple one. Can any one tell how to do this...

Comment: Can you explain the question better, please, I'm not really sure what you want

Comment: Actually i am saving my data according the code above in two different text files with different name. Now what i need is if i select an option from my combo box from  front end as some X and click on save i would like to save the data present on that form in a text file . And if i select other option as Y i would like to append that form data to the same text file. And at the same i would like to save it in different text files

Comment: Initially i am saving it to 2 different files now i would like to save it in a single file as well as with different file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want something like this.

Your data looks the same each time (or at least I can't see how the data differs) but I'm sure that you'll get the gist.

You need to use File.Append to add new data to a file and File.Open to clear and write new data. Call MergedDataWrite twice. If you need to write several files to it.

```
public void SeparateDataWrite()
{
  if (m_strStandardEntryClassCode == "PPD")
  {
    m_strPath += "/PPD_BatchHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
  }
  else
  {
    m_strPath += "/CCD_BatchHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
  }

  using (StreamWriter w = File.Open(m_strPath, FileMode.Create)
  {
    WriteData(w);
    w.close();
  }
}

public MergedDataWrite()
{
  using (StreamWriter w = File.Append("somefilename.txt")
  {
    WriteData(w);
    w.Close();
  }
}

public void WriteData(TextWriter tw)
{
            tw.Write(m_strRecordTypeCode.PadLeft(1, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strServiceClassCode.PadLeft(3, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyName.PadRight(16, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyDiscretionaryData.PadRight(20, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyIdentification.PadRight(10, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strStandardEntryClassCode.PadRight(3, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyEntryDescription.PadRight(10, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strCompanyDescriptiveDate.PadLeft(6, '0'));
            string m_strEffDate = m_strEffectiveEntryDate.Replace("/", "");
            tw.Write(m_strEffDate.PadLeft(6, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strOriginatorStatusCode.PadRight(1, ' '));
            tw.Write(m_strOriginationDFIIdentification.PadLeft(8, '0'));
            tw.Write(m_strBatchNumber.PadLeft(7, '0'));
            tw.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Various ways you can do it, I'd suggest.

1. Copy file number 1 to a file called what the single combined file should be called.
2. Open the new file (the single combined file) for appending.
3. Open file number 2 for reading and read in all the contents.
4. Write the data you've just read in to the single combined file.

This [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sonuraj/MergeTwoFiles04082008144204PM/MergeTwoFiles.aspx) has a simple code sample for doing something similar.

Another option would be to store all the data in memory and then write the 3 files straight from memory.

Comment: At the time of clicking on save is it possible to save